# mobile web app - ask which number to call

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, call

Is it possible to have a call link pop up and show two numbers?

Basically I have two locations and want one call button. when tapped it asked which location. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm sure if you think about it, you'll come-up with some way to ask a user to choose option A or option B.

Comment: Actually no, the ability to allow a  user to select one of two options has never been implemented--in any language.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a jQuery mobile [dialog](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html).

And the content of the dialog would look something like this :

```
<div data-role="dialog">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <h1>Dialog</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
        <h1>Which location?</h1>
        <p>Wich number do you wan't to call</p>
        <a href="tel:+440000000000" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b">First location</a>
        <a href="tel:+440000000000" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b">Second location</a>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Where "+440000000000" is the phone number.
As @Shae said, a little bit of research and you would have come up with something like that.

Hope that helps! Have a nice day.